# ORA-00902: invalid datatype while creating table

Tags: oracle, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE INTERVIEW_DETAILS
(
interview_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
interview_date DATE,
sr_executive_name VARCHAR2(25),
jr_executive_name VARCHAR2(25),
designation VARCHAR2(20),
jobseeker_name VARCHAR2(25),
skills VARCHAR2(20),
inetview_status VARCHAR2(20),
recruiter_id NUMBER,
recruiter_name VARCHAR2(25),
recruiter_location VARCHAR2(20),
jobseeker_contact VARCHAR2(20),
jobseeker_email VARCHAR2(50),
quailification VARCHAR2(20),
jobseeker_dob DATE, 
total_experience NUMBER,
rel_experience NUMBER,
inhand_ctc LOB,
expected_ctc LOB,
notice_period VARCHAR2(20),
cv_status VARCHAR2(20),
interview_type VARCHAR2(20),
attn_Y/N VARCHAR2(10),
fianl_remark VARCHAR2(15),
offer_date DATE,
offer_ctc LOB,
joining_date DATE,
joined_Y/N VARCHAR2(10),

CONSTRAINT INTERVIEW_DETAILS_fk FOREIGN KEY(sr_executive_name) 
REFERENCES SR_EXECUTIVE(sr_executive_name),

CONSTRAINT INTERVIEW_DETAILS_fk FOREIGN KEY(jr_executive_name) 
REFERENCES JR_EXECUTIVE(jr_executive_name),

CONSTRAINT INTERVIEW_DETAILS_fk FOREIGN KEY(jobseeker_name) 
REFERENCES JOBSEEKER(Name),

CONSTRAINT INTERVIEW_DETAILS_fk FOREIGN KEY(recruiter_id) 
REFERENCES RECRUITER(recruiter_id),

CONSTRAINT INTERVIEW_DETAILS_fk FOREIGN KEY(recruiter_name) 
REFERENCES RECRUITER(recruiter_name),

CONSTRAINT INTERVIEW_DETAILS_fk FOREIGN KEY(recruiter_location) 
REFERENCES RECRUITER(recruiter_location),

CONSTRAINT INTERVIEW_DETAILS_fk FOREIGN KEY(jobseeker_contact) 
REFERENCES JOBSEEKER(Contact),

CONSTRAINT INTERVIEW_DETAILS_fk FOREIGN KEY(jobseeker_email) 
REFERENCES JOBSEEKER(Email),

CONSTRAINT INTERVIEW_DETAILS_fk FOREIGN KEY(jobseeker_dob) 
REFERENCES JOBSEEKER(DOB)
)
```

Comment: There is no `LOB` data type. Please read the manual

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT513)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `LOB` data type. Instead, you can use one of these:

- [`Clob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefclob.html)
- [`Blob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefblob.html)
- `nclob` (I couldn't find a link)

See also:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm

Comment: Since this is your first answer, please refer to the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer website on how to write good answers. In this case it would be great to include a small description to help the question owner decide between the given possibilities.